# Why Bootstrap Shows Columns With Space

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have made a simple section in Bootstrap which contains 6 columns. So I did this in the html:

```
<div id="content">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                        <div class="box one">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                        <div class="box two">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                        <div class="box three">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                        <div class="box four">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                        <div class="box five">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                        <div class="box six">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

But when I test it in browser it shows me this:

[image]

So as you can see, I have mentioned out the parts which has EXTRA SPACE and I don't why!

And here's the css code:

```
.box{
height:200px;
width:100%;
}

.one{background-color:#A0522D;}
.two{background-color:#FAFAD2;}
.three{background-color:#F08080;}
.four{background-color:#778899;}
.five{background-color: #FFA07A;}
.six{background-color:#20B2AA;}
```

So what's going wrong here and why I am getting these unknown spaces between the columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because by default, boostrap has a `padding-left` and `padding-right` of `15px`, so just reset it.

```css
.box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}

[class*="col-"] {
  padding: 0 !important
}

.one {
  background-color: #A0522D;
}

.two {
  background-color: #FAFAD2;
}

.three {
  background-color: #F08080;
}

.four {
  background-color: #778899;
}

.five {
  background-color: #FFA07A;
}

.six {
  background-color: #20B2AA;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="content">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <div class="box one">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <div class="box two">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <div class="box three">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <div class="box four">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <div class="box five">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <div class="box six">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```